# How to transform an excel table in a xml file?

Tags: xml, excel

I have an Excel file with three worksheets. One of these sheets is a table with 3500 lines, each with 200 columns.
I need to turn this table into an xml file with the following form:

```
<xml>
    <element columm1="attribute1" columm2="attribute2" />
</xml>
```

Where "columnN" is the name of each column and "attributeN" is the value of it for each line.
Each "element" represents a table row.

I do not know what would be the simplest way to do this.
I believe this could be done using macros or VBA, but I'm not sure because I do not know the language well.

Ideally, the process could be adapted if the table format change (with more rows or columns) or excel file changes (including more spreadsheets, for example).
Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Excel supports saving as an XML file, but it's not pretty. You could write an XSLT to transform it to your preferred format. Also, I'm not sure how XML readers will perform with an element having 200 attributes.

Comment: Is this a required format? As @jnpcl said, 200 attributes may cause problems. There are better ways to handle this, if you're interested in other ideas.

Comment: Yes, the output format need to be with all columms as attibutes. The XML I'll be used in a system that uses this in this way.

Comment: And, as a note, i try to save the Excel sheet as .xml and did not work. Don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
Sub ToXML()


MyFile = "data.xml"
fnum = FreeFile()
Open MyFile For Output As fnum

Dim n As Integer
n = 3 'Number of DATA rows

Dim m As Integer
m = 2 ' Number of columns

Print #fnum, "<xml>"

For i = 2 To n + 1
    Print #fnum, "<element ";
    For j = 1 To m
        Print #fnum, Cells(1, j).Value & "=""" & Cells(i, j).Value & """ ";
    Next j
Print #fnum, "/>"
Next i

Print #fnum, "</xml>"
Close #fnum
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe i misspoke here. The name of the attribute isn't really "column", instead is the actual name of the column in the Excel table.

Comment: @Daniel Are the names found in the first row?

Comment: R. Worked just fine. Many tanks.